# Auto generate css variables by SASS function

Tags: css, sass, mixins, css-variables

I want to ask how I can auto-generate css variable by sass function

for example:
I want this variable to auto-generate

```
:root{--sample1:red;}
```

SASS function:

```
@function brand($key,$val) {
 //this not works  
 :root{
    --#{$key}:$val;
  }
@return val(--#{$val});}
```

use the brand function

```
   header{
       background-color:brand("sample1",red)
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by auto generate?

Comment: I mean generate variable my SASS function

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything. Give us the input and expected output and the method you wish to use. Do you mean by using a preprocessor? How should it auto-generate?

Comment: Atleast your `var(--#{$val})` is wrong as it should be `#{$key}`

Comment: This guy uses maps to create something similar. 
His approach is interesting and maybe it helps you to find a better way to resolve your problem: https://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/post/css4-variables-and-sass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieved something similar, here is the idea.

```
$spacing: (
  none: none,
  01: 4px,
  02: 8px,
  03: 16px,
  04: 24px,
  05: 32px,
  06: 40px,
  07: 48px,
  08: 56px,
  09: 64px,
  10: 72px,
  11: 80px,
  12: 88px,
  13: 96px
);

:root {
  // SPACING Custom Properties
  @each $space, $value in $spacing {
    --spacing-#{$space}: #{$value};
  }
}
```